# private static final in detail please

Tags: static, private, final

What is the use if we use private static final to create an object of a class which is in another package..??

package pack1;

class C1{

...

}

class L1{

...

}

package pack2;

import pack1.C1;

import pack1.L1;

public class Main{

private static final C1 c1=new C1();

private static final L1 l1=new L1();

public static void main(String args[]){

...

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first result on Google!

http://geekwhorled.blogspot.com/2004/07/simple-java-questions-1-private-static.html